# Compound IDENTITY column in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, identity, identity-column

- An Orders table has a CustomerId column and an OrderId column.
- For certain reasons it's *important* that an order's id is no longer than 2-bytes.
- There will be several million orders in total, which makes 2-bytes not enough for a global order id.
- A customer will have no more than several thousand orders making 2-bytes enough.
- The obvious solution is to have the (CustomerId, CustomerOrderNumber) be unique rather than OrderId itself.

**The problem** is generating the *next* CustomerOrderId. Preferably, without creating a separate table for each customer (even if it contains only an IDENTITY column), in order to keep the upper layers of the solution simple.

Q: **how would you generate the next OrderId so that (CustomerId, CustomerOrderId) is unique but CustomerOrderNumber itself is allowed to have repetitions? Does Sql Server 2008 have a built in functionality for doing this?**

For lack of a better term I'm calling it a Compound IDENTITY column.

Comment: `OrderID` is perhaps better named `CustomerOrderNumber`, since it does not ID an individual order on its own.

Comment: @OrbMan: You're right. I've changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Output table (orderID smallint)  --smallint=2 bytes

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO ORDERS
        (CustomerId ,OrderId ,.....)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.OrderId 
        INTO @Output 
    SELECT
        @CustomerId ,ISNULL(MAX(OrderId),0)+1, @...
        FROM ORDERS WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE CustomerId=@CustomerId 

--any other processing, can use just generated @Output.OrderId value if necessary

COMMIT
```

make sure you have a unqiue index/constraint on CustomerId ,OrderId

Answer (score 1):

I would set a Unique Constraint on the combination of CustomerId and OrderId.

I thing something along these lines should do for you:

```
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [UQ_CustomerOrders] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerId] ASC,
    [OrderId] ASC,
)
```

Comment: how will OrderId be incremented for each insert?

Comment: @AllenG: That's a good start, but how do I determine the next value?

Comment: To create the new Id, you'd probably need KM's solution.  I was reading the question to be how would SQL2k8 ensure that the combination is unique while allowing repitition within either column.

Comment: OK. That's useful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this will probably help you: [Custom Auto-Generated Sequences with SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server)

Comment: +1: It purposes several good methods and principles for any such chosen solution.